# Why aren't these Dojo hover events working?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

I'm new to Dojo (quite experienced in jQuery) for a project, and am working on adding/removing some classes that will change styles for main navigation links and drop-downs.

Here is the code I've written:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    dojo.query('#primary-nav > ul > li > div').forEach(function(container) {
        var hoverToggles = dojo.query('> a, > ul', container),
            link = dojo.query('> a', container);

        dojo.connect(link, 'onmouseover', function() {
            dojo.addClass(hoverToggles, 'hover');
        });

        dojo.connect(link, 'onmouseout', function() {           
            dojo.removeClass(hoverToggles, 'hover');
        });
    });
});
```

No code placed into the event handlers is run (console.log, alert). Values for `link` and `hoverToggles` are correct.

Am I doing something wrong here? 
Side question: Is there a more Dojo-idiomatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dojo.query()` returns a NodeList. `dojo.addClass()` and the rest work with DOM nodes.

Try something like that:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
  dojo.query('#primary-nav > ul > li > div').forEach(function(container) {
    var hoverToggles = dojo.query('> a, > ul', container),
        link = dojo.query('> a', container);

    link.onmouseover(function() {
      hoverToggles.addClass('hover');
    });

    link.onmouseout(function() {            
      hoverToggles.removeClass('hover');
    });
  });
});
```